# Is my design optimal?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I wanted to switch an LED ON and OFF using a signal from an Arduino. The LED was a high power LED, which I choose to overdrive with 100 mA with voltage source of 12 V. Forward voltage drop of the LED is 4 V.

The switching was done using a BC547b transistor, which has an 2.5kohm resistance on its base leg to the Arduino pin. Base current is 100mA/200

I choose to use BC547b as it seems an all purpose transistor, but by further inspecting the transistor I saw that its collector Imax is rated to 200mA (good thing I didn't supply it with more than 12 V or designed the resistor not to pull more than 100mA).

Emitter was grounded.

But other than that I can see than efficiency-wise it uses "a lot" of power, it's not fully saturated... The transistor didn't exhibit that much heat? So I am not sure whether it is a good thing, or a bad thing.

But other than that, what parameters should I look into to choose the transistor to switch this form of circuit?

How can I choose, in general, an ideal transistor in relation to speed, power usage and handling of high frequent signals?

**I know for certain that my Arduino pin output is 3.3 V (might be a fake model).  But that is for sure.**

Circuit

[image]

Are my design choices optimal for this application?

R1 =  2500 ohm
R2 =  4 ohm. 
V_c = 3.3 v
V_{cc} = 12 V

Comment: Is the LED one with an integral resistor designed to work directly on 12V? Your base resistor current is: 5V (arduino output) - 0.7V (base emitter saturation volts) / 2500 or about 1.7mA. Assuming hfe of 100 will give collector current of 172 mA (if nothing else limiting the current).

Comment: Output from aurdino is calculated to give out 3.3 V.
hfe  = 200 from data sheet
Thus  Ic = 200 * (3.3-0.7)/2500

But the  collector is limited to only draw 100 mA by a resistor on the collector leg.

Comment: OK but note that hfe is only valid when the transistor is **not** in saturation ! Since you want to use it as a switch you **do** want to drive it into saturation. The trick to do that is to provide it with enough base current so that the transistor lets as much collector current flow as possible. The 2.5 kohm resistor should be able to provide enough base current for that even from a 3.3 V arduino output.

Comment: Exactly.. Mine is not saturated..  Or so do i think. V_ce = 12V and I_c = 100mA

Comment: I think it is in saturation though. In doubt you can measure it. Measure Ic, if it is 100 mA and determined by the LED, the voltage across the transistor will be small, like less than 500 mV. Then you're in saturation. If the current is less than 100 mA and the transistor is limiting the current, it's Vce will be more than 1 V, then the transistor is **not** in saturation. I think you will need a much larger base resistor (more than 10 kohm) to be  in the non-saturated region.

Comment: *"V_ce = 12V and I_c = 100mA"* That cannot be true at the same time, your transistor would get **HOT** and burn out.

Comment: That was my conclusion as well.. 
But it doesn't happen?

Comment: No, not **at the same time**. It is a common misunderstanding. When the transistor is **off** no current flows so Ic = 0 and Vce is 12 V because the transistor behaves as an open circuit. No current flows so no power is dissipated and all is well :-)  When the transistor is **on**, current will flow so Ic = 100 mA and Vce will be small, like less than 500 mV. This again results in a low power dissipation in the transistor so it is happy and all is well again :-)

Comment: But is it a proper choice? drawing current from an arduino isn't the best thing to do, and what about rise time?, does it react quickly enough?

Comment: I am not sure i understand why V_ce = 500mv => why exactly 500mV?

Comment: _"which I choose to overdrive with 100 mA"_, why are you doing this? You'll severely reducing the life of the LED.

Comment: To make the light brighter.. I know it is not recommended, but it was only going to be used a few times, so i didn't it as a problem to overdrive it.

Comment: *"why exactly 500mV?"* I **never** wrote **exactly 500 mV**. I made a very rough assumption. It could be 600 mV or 400 mV. The exact value does not matter, most of the 12 V will be across the LED and/or series resistor. As long as the voltage across the transistor is significanly smaller than 12 V, it will be OK.

Comment: But how did you get that value? 
I mean the forward voltage across the diode is 4V so V_ce should be 8V when  the switch is on?  I am not sure i get how it could be 500 mV, i think you are right, but i don't get how?

Comment: Another thing is that the Ic is rated to max 100 mA meaning that if the power source ripples a bit, a would not be able to operate properly.

Answer (score 3):

> The switching was done using an transistor bc547b. Which has an
>   2.5kohm resistent on its base leg to the aurdino pin. Base current is 100mA/200

No, this is untrue. The base current IS NOT 100 mA. Some arduinos run from 5V and some 3V3. I have assumed 3V3 and if the GPIO pin driving the base were high, the likely current you have flowing into the base is: -

I = \$\dfrac{3.3V - 0.6V}{2500\Omega}\$ = 1.08 mA.

The 0.6V comes from the forward volt drop of the base-emitter in the BC547.

So, irrespective of the collector current being maybe a problem, you are driving it with 1 mA and not 100 mA. FYI the arduino's GPIO pins cannot source anything like 100 mA.

If you want to drive 100 mA into the LED then a BC547 can do this but you will probably need a current limiting resistor in series with the LED. I'd consider reducing the base resistor to something like 470 ohms and putting a 100 ohm resistor in series with the LED BUT, this all assumes you have a fairly standard high power LED with a forward volt drop of 2 or 3 volts.

You have not disclosed this information so, you need to research this and possibly come back with a link to the data sheet.

Comment: He meant 100 mA / hfe which is better but still incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You want the BC547b to drop as little Vce as possible, if you drop say 500 mV that will result in 500 mV x 100 mA = 50 mW. Not a lot and the BC547b can handle that easily.

The base current will **not** be Ic / beta = 100 mA / 200 for several reasons. You defined Ib already with your 2.5 k ohm base resistor !

Assuming the Arduino is running on a 5 V supply, also assuming that the Vbe of the BC547b is 0.7 V, then I(Rb) will be (5 V - 0.7 V)/ 2.5 kohm = 1.7 mA.

Since your Ic is 100 mA then beta would be 100 mA / 1.7 mA = 59. But actually the BC547b will have a considerably higher beta than 59, even at Ic = 100 mA. So the BC547b will be in saturation, which is good.

This all looks fine to me :-)

Sure you can optimize to the whatever but you have to ask yourself: what will I gain from that ? I would say: nothing worth your time.

Comment: Just a side note, to get more efficiency out of the circuit, since each LED drops 4v at 100mA, put two of them in series and decrease R2 accordingly. The loss across R2 will be less, since it is dropping less voltage. I would not use three LEDs (4v x 3 = 12v) with a 0Ω resistor because it offers no over-current protection. (Any spike on the 12v rail would probably destroy the BC547B.)

Comment: Very bad answer. For the transistor to be in saturation you should assume hfe of 10 to 20. Active mode gain does not equal saturation mode gain. Base current must be in the range 5 to 10 mA if you don't want the transistor to dissipate unwanted power.

Comment: I think pumping 10 mA into the base wastes an equal amount of power. Your comment suggests that you **must** be in deep saturation. I don't think that is needed, it works fine when the transistor is just a little bit into saturation. But if I'm wrong and it doesn't work please prove it so I can learn something.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The datasheet shows a saturation voltages plot at hfe = 10. But that is **not** a property of the transistor ! It is a **test condition**. You could make a similar plot for the condition hfe = 59 (like in my answer). Then Vce_sat will be higher of course. But the transistor **is** still in saturation mode.

Comment: @FakeMoustache - If VCE is greater than VBE, the transistor is, by definition, not in saturation. At these current levels it _may_ saturate - but it may not. For instance, running a simulation (TINA) gives saturation with the 2.5k base resistor and 100 mA, but a 3k base resistor does not saturate.

Comment: And 2.5 k is what was used so the transistor is *just* in saturation as was my intention.